# How to disable specific month between min and max of input type=month?

Tags: html

When using `<input type="month">` with `min` and `max`, for example:

```
<input type="month" min="2020-01" max="2020-12">
```

Is it possible to disable certain months between them?

Comment: it isn't possible. You need some js logic to have your own custom month picker. Or you may add some validation but it's not what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of a library where I can choose to show only month pick without days and disable months?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a custom JavaScript library or a third-party date picker component. I had something on my pc about this one. Modify it to work as you want.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="date-picker" />
    <script>
      const disabledMonths = [5, 6, 7];

      flatpickr("#date-picker", {
        minDate: "2020-01",
        maxDate: "2020-12",
        mode: "month",
        disable: [
          function(date) {
            return disabledMonths.includes(date.getMonth());
          }
        ]
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible with flatpickr to only display months/years without days?

Comment: Yes by setting the mode option to "month" or "year". For example:
   flatpickr("#date-picker", {
        mode: "month"

Comment: I just tried and also looked at your code snippet, the days are still visible

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Such widgets are built into browsers. Of course, in different cases a certain control is given. In this case, the maximum possible is to use the native argument **step**. For example:

```html
    <input type="month" min="2020-01" max="2021-02" step="2" />
```